# How to replace input arguments using ByteBuddy's @Advice.AllArguments?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am using ByteBuddy's `@Advice` to transform my classes and it works fine until I try to replace input arguments.

I have a `FooService` with a `join` method which just joins two strings with a space.

```java
public class FooService {
    public String join(String message, String message1) {
        return message + " " + message1;
    }
}
```

And I have another method which takes a `Object[] args` array input and changes elements in the array.

```java
    public static ArgsProcessor argsProcessor = args -> {
        args[0] = args[0] + "-suffix";
        args[1] = "replaced";
    };
```

I've tried different ways to use the `argsProcessor` to manipulate the input arguments in `@Advice.OnMethodEnter` method. For me, the following advice implementations are almost equivalent and should all work, somehow only `Advice1` works.

```java
    public static class Advice1 {
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void onEnter(@Advice.AllArguments(readOnly = false, typing = Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC) Object[] args) {
            Object[] newArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
            ArgsProcessor argsProcessor = Demo.argsProcessor;
            argsProcessor.process(newArgs);
            args = newArgs;
        }
    }

    public static class Advice2 {
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void onEnter(@Advice.AllArguments(readOnly = false, typing = Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC) Object[] args) {
            Object[] newArgs = new Object[args.length];
            ArgsProcessor argsProcessor = Demo.argsProcessor;
            argsProcessor.process(args);
            System.arraycopy(args, 0, newArgs, 0, args.length);
            args = newArgs;
        }
    }

    public static class Advice3 {
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void onEnter(@Advice.AllArguments(readOnly = false, typing = Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC) Object[] args) {
            Object[] newArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
            try {
                ArgsProcessor argsProcessor = Demo.argsProcessor;
                argsProcessor.process(newArgs);
                args = newArgs;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Advice4 {
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void onEnter(@Advice.AllArguments(readOnly = false, typing = Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC) Object[] args) {
            ArgsProcessor argsProcessor = Demo.argsProcessor;
            argsProcessor.process(args);
        }
    }

    public static class Advice5 {
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void onEnter(@Advice.AllArguments(readOnly = false, typing = Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC) Object[] args) {
            ArgsProcessor argsProcessor = Demo.argsProcessor;
            argsProcessor.process(args);
            args = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
        }
    }
```

Output

```
Advice1 a-suffix replaced
Advice2 a b
Advice3 a b
Advice4 a b
Advice5 a b
```

The code snippet https://gist.github.com/raptium/ab7830e5d7f7cba43bbd2c2a5c7b38e0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code, I get

```
Advice1 a-suffix replaced 
Advice2 a b 
Advice3 a-suffix replaced 
Advice4 a b 
Advice5 a b
```

what is what I expect. Byte Buddy uses advice methods as templates. This code is not really exeucted. When you read `args` in your method, Byte Buddy **creates a new array every time**.

Therefore, computing `args == args` would return `false` since Byte Buddy creates a new array containing all arguments every time! If you change the args array, you have to write it back for Byte Buddy to discover the corresponding byte code and to map it back to an assignment.